# concatenate date + time to make timestamp

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am using dbt and snowflake to parse a json.. Currently, I parse two cols, date and time separately. Now, I want to concatenate both and assign the type `timestamp`to them

```
SELECT 
    JSON_DATA:"Required_Collect_Time_From"::time as "REQUIRED_COLLECT_TIME_FROM",
    JSON_DATA:"Required_Collect_Date"::time as "REQUIRED_COLLECT_DATE",
FROM {{ source('INGEST_DATA', 'LOAD' ) }}
```

I tried this::

```
    timestamp_ntz_from_parts(JSON_DATA:"Required_Collect_Date"::date,  JSON_DATA:"Required_Collect_Time_From":time) as "REQUIRED_TIMESTAMP",
```

However, the col "REQUIRED_TIMESTAMP" is just always empty in my final table. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume **JSON_DATA:"Required_Collect_Time_From":time** has a typo in here, as it should be **JSON_DATA:"Required_Collect_Time_From"::time**.

Both these variations works for me:

```
select timestamp_ntz_from_parts(to_date('2013-04-05'), to_time('12:00:00'));
select timestamp_ntz_from_parts('2013-04-05'::date, '12:00:00'::time);
```

Comment: So, for example, my time was 09:30:00. In the timestamp, it is showing date 08:30:00. One hour behind. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: and if the time column is NULL, then what would happen?

Comment: The data is always stored in GMT/UTC and is displayed based on session/user/account **TIMEZONE** parameter. If the column is NULL you'll get NULL back. Try for example: **select timestamp_ntz_from_parts(to_date('2013-04-05'), to_time(NULL));
select timestamp_ntz_from_parts('2013-04-05'::date, NULL::time);**

Comment: is it possible to maybe check if the time is null? If so, just return the date otherwise the full time stamp?

Comment: you can surround `to_time` with `ifnull` to help the NULL case.